# Getting index of element close to end of list

Tags: python, list, optimization, indexing

I have a sorted list containing **objects**, and I would like to get the first index of the last value (which is retrieved by using the **get_val** method) of the list. I wrote this function but I was wondering if there is any way to optimize this even more?

```
def index_last_value(tbl, get_val=lambda obj:obj):
    tbl_len, prev_v = len(tbl), get_val(tbl[-1])
    for i,v in enumerate(reversed(tbl)):
        v = get_val(v)
        if v == prev_v:
            index = tbl_len-i-1
        if v != prev_v or i+1 == tbl_len:
            return index
        prev_v = v

class MyObject:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v

tbl_1 = list(map(MyObject, [1,1]))
tbl_2 = list(map(MyObject, [1,1,2,2,2]))
index_last_value(tbl_1, get_val=lambda obj:obj.v)  # -> 0
index_last_value(tbl_2, get_val=lambda obj:obj.v)  # -> 2
```

**EDIT**: The list doesn't contain numbers, it contains objects.

Comment: `lst.index(lst[-1])`…?

Comment: Yeah figured that out 1 minute after posting this question... will update the question because i realized this is not my use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ~33% faster (for the data given):

```
def index_last_value2(tbl, get_val=lambda obj:obj):
    prev_v = get_val(tbl[-1])
    for i in range(len(tbl) - 2, -1, -1):
        if get_val(tbl[i]) != prev_v:
            return i + 1
    return 0
```

You could get another ~15% of speepdup by changing argument `get_val` function into name of attribute:

```
def index_last_value3(tbl, val_name):
    prev_v = tbl[-1].__dict__[val_name]
    for i in range(len(tbl) - 2, -1, -1):
        if tbl[i].__dict__[val_name] != prev_v:
            return i + 1
    return 0
index_last_value3(tbl_1, val_name='v')
index_last_value3(tbl_2, val_name='v')
```

Profiling in reverse order to make sure RAM operations do not favor optimized versions:

```
    44      1001       2682.0      2.7      3.8      for _ in range(1000):
    45      1000       6420.0      6.4      9.1          index_last_value3(tbl_1, val_name='v')
    46      1000       7857.0      7.9     11.1          index_last_value3(tbl_2, val_name='v')
    47      1001       2745.0      2.7      3.9      for _ in range(1000):
    48      1000       7676.0      7.7     10.9          index_last_value2(tbl_1, get_val=lambda obj: obj.v)
    49      1000      10370.0     10.4     14.7          index_last_value2(tbl_2, get_val=lambda obj:obj.v)
    50      1001       2670.0      2.7      3.8      for _ in range(1000):
    51      1000      12083.0     12.1     17.1          index_last_value(tbl_1, get_val=lambda obj: obj.v)
    52      1000      18007.0     18.0     25.5          index_last_value(tbl_2, get_val=lambda obj: obj.v)
```

Comment: Thank a lot for your answer @dankal444, I learned a few things I didn't know about Python from it! :)

Comment: Side question... did you use `cProfile` to generate the snippet at the bottom?

Comment: @AmineKchouk no at all, I used [line_profiler](https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler)

Answer (score 0):

**General answer**

We scan the list from its beginning to its end

```
def index_last_value(tbl, get_val=lambda obj:obj):
    lastv = get_val(tbl[-1])
    for i,v in enumerate(tbl):
        if get_val(v) == lastv:
            return i
```

**Special case** : the values are contiguous (ie. there is no gap) :
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2] is possible, [1, 1, 2, 3, 2] is not.

We scan the list from end to its beginning,

We could reverse the list but we can also do without reversing it:

```
def index_last_value(tbl, get_val=lambda obj:obj):
    len_tbl = len(tbl)
    if len_tbl == 1:
        return 0
    lastv = get_val(tbl[-1])
    for i,v in enumerate(tbl[-2::-1]):
        if get_val(v) != lastv:
            return len_tbl - i - 1
    return 0
```

Comment: I decided against this, because since I know the value I'm looking for is at the end of the list, it would require a fewer number of iterations (don't know at what point this becomes more efficient, since there is less content in your proposed for loop)

Comment: @AmineKchouk, maybe you should specify that the value is near the end of the list in the question.

Comment: @AmineKchouk, even if the position is near the end of the list, you can't really be sure you've found it until you've scanned the entire list; unless the maximum width of the hole can be provided otherwise.

Comment: I thought this was clear enough with me saying "I have a sorted list [...] and I would like to get the first index of the last value" :S

Comment: @AmineKchouk, Yes clear enough. By the way I ran so tests under the hypothesis that the ending packet length is the square root of the whole list :dankal444 solutions are the fastest, yours only 2 times slower and mines come well after.